# How to protect js from custom events

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events, easeljs

I am writing a game on Javascript with canvas and easeljs and I wonder if there are any ways to protect it. For example, I use `stage.Addchild(index)` to add a new object to the stage. Simply editing DOM I can attatch new event handler and fire it, something like `<body onclick="stage.removeChild(0)">` and this will remove all the stage objects one by one.

I was thinking to filter all the coming events and check what had fired it. But I am not sure how to do that and there may be better ways to make it... Please point me in the right direction...

Comment: I have to ask - why bother? This is a serious question.

Comment: I don't have a great answer for ya, I can say putting your js through something like [Google Closure](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) will make it much harder to read and rewite at runtime.  Mainly wanted to point out, if you're making a game with javascript, you should really check-out [gameQuery](http://gamequeryjs.com/).  Makes writing full sprite based games for browsers a breeze and even has some security to ensure or help reduce cheating.

Comment: because a gamer can change some properties and cheat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to protect your Javascript is put all of your initialization code into closures and not expose anything against global variables.

However, this only provides some guarantees against run-time namespace clashes and is meant to be used as good development practice.

You cannot trust any code run on the client side; for anti-cheat behavior you need to check incoming inputs on the server-side. The users have 100% control over what is running in their browsers and this includes control to modify your code any way they wish.

Comment: "for anti-cheat behavior you need to check incoming inputs on the server-side." I may be wrong, but to check them on the server-side I need to send a query to the server from the client side, and any query can be caught and modified in browser.