# Questions regarding JavaScript, WebSockets, WebGL

Tags: javascript, websocket, webgl

I've seen a lot of stackoverflow questions regarding the other client side scripting languages

The Internet is becoming a very content-rich and dynamic place. HTML and CSS specifications are trying to bring the Web to the next level - we are getting WebSockets support which is real nice for full-duplex client-server communication, enabling some fascinating design patterns to emerge. Also, we have a working implementation of WebGL in JavaScript with which I've had a lot of fun thus far.

But this has brought up some concerns, at least for me. I'm a desktop programmer, C/C++/Objective-C - depending on the platform. Specifically, a rendering architect. JavaScript has served all of us marvelously, has it not? We've used it for getting basic user interactions with 2D *linear* websites, responding to simple events and combining all that with HTML and CSS.

**Given the fact that the doors of realtime communication and GPU-driven visualization have been opened to the web, will this have any implications on JavaScript?** I've seen the reactions to Dart and other attempts at pushing JavaScript out. JavaScript is weakly-typed, which sounds all sorts of alarms for me (considering the intense math library which hangs on speed, unnecessary runtime checking is not a fun time).

I've shifted a lot of the code to the GPU, but even then my in-house renderer is simply CPU-bound (the HD6990 can't be the problem, let alone the code which powers the desktop/embedded engine).

So, here is it out in the front:

- Code is **lying naked** because of the interpreter design. Rendering technology and solutions are worth a lot of money. It's the sole foundation of my company and pays the bills. Obfuscation doesn't cut it (Do correct me if I'm wrong). I've always wondered, **why isn't there an intermediate compilation process to a form of bytecode which can be processed by the VM?**
- It is weakly typed. Juggling matrices, vectors, quaternions, arrays and all other sorts of data common to highly-interactive applications just bloats processing with runtime checking. Even though it eventually goes to the GPU side, you still have to do a fair amount of work on the CPU side which is bogged down by JavaScript.
- Prototype-based paradigm will dampen efforts to port rendering code from major players who can push adoption of WebGL/WebSockets. (remember that a lot of it is driven by the CPU). **Will the prototype-based paradigm persist as more and more users start demanding high fidelity 2D/3D content?**
- WebSockets have proven to be a beautiful new addition to web gaming (BrowserQuest), not to mention dynamic websites, and will be driven by a lot of people in the future to develop awesome content ( my company is running a little closed project that implements a small MMO in a 3D environment driven by WebSockets ).

**So, do my concerns have any basis in reality?**

**Are there any new movements in regard to these problems?**

If you offer any answers to the topic, could you also add a small paragraph of personal opinion? I know it's not the "way of the Stackexchange", but it doesn't harm since all the other questions are legitimate and answers can be based in fact.

Comment: These are interesting issues. However, it feels like the wrong style of question for StackOverflow. It seems like a great fit for a blog post or Google+ conversation though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your concerns are based on misunderstanding how Javascript run-times work and mostly have no basis in reality.

- All Javascript code is JIT'ed nowadays - intermediate bytecode language is not needed and was orignally seen possible hinderance of portability, which is the top virtue of web. Modern scripting like programming languages like Python, Ruby, PHP etc. work well even if the apps are not distributed as bytecode. Bytecode step is not needed, as code is JIT'ed in the end anyway. More material you can provide for JIT to work with, the better. In fact for Java they disabled bytecode optimizations in modern versions because it was confusing JIT compiler.
- JIT compilation can optimize out dynamic typing issues, though they will never provide statically typed performance, but most likely will provide good enough performance. There are some issues though http://www.scirra.com/blog/76/how-to-write-low-garbage-real-time-javascript but Javascript implementations are getting better to work around these kind of issues. For example, Mozilla Audio team (which seem to be more like demo team...) is cranking out 3D demos just to have material to optimize their Javascript run-time.
- I don't see why prototype based approach would have any connection to high fidelity, they are two totally separate things
- Currently the alternative approaches like Google NaCL are not endorsed by other browser vendors and most likely never will, as Microsoft and Apple would not adopt Google-only technologies and Mozilla sees NaCL as threat to open web

For insight how modern JIT compiles work please see PyPy blog http://morepypy.blogspot.com/ (though not Javascript specific). They go to great detail explaining what kind of JIT optimizations modern computer science applies on the code.

For what "web-like design patterns can achieve in 3D" please see tQuery which is jQuery like framework for 3D content https://github.com/jeromeetienne/tquery

Cheers,
Mikko

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, what I meant to imply by the demand for high fidelity content is the fact that most modern engines are based on the class-based object oriented paradigm with some data-oriented approaches to remove some of the bloat inherent to classic object-oriented programming. Rewriting a huge codebase to comply with JavaScript is the only option - hence a big time investment, thus financial as well. But that still leaves all the code lying naked, one of my primary concerns. Is obfuscating really the only solution?

Comment: Your client side code is never protected and can be always disassembled, etc.. Thus, Javascript guys tend to call "obfuscation" to "minification" which eliminates bandwidth overhead :)

Comment: Related answer (few minute ago) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794182/how-to-protect-js-from-custom-events/10043479#10043479

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, kind sir! I think this answers pretty much all of my questions.

Comment: Also if you want to start huge codebase from the scratch I'd suggest check CoffeeScript or Google Dash. The former provides better syntax and some high level construct Javascript lacks (like class), Dash provides statical typing. Both compile down to Javascript. For both the current debugging support, due to additional compilation step, is little lacking in browsers.

Comment: Also and as far as I know I am yet to be knighted by the queen of England :)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I wish I could give you +2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

- **Javascript code is lying naked**: it sounds like your question is about protecting "intellectual property". I think you are overestimating the protection that compilation provides. Compilation hides your algorithms only marginally better than good obfuscation; a good decompiler will reveal most of what you are trying to hide anyways. Compilation and obfuscation only protect your from the curious not from people who are determined to steal your ideas. If you want to protect the form of your code, that's what copyright is for. I will also point out that one of the very reasons for the success of the web platform is in fact "view source". It is probably the greatest educational tool for somebody wanting to learn how to design great web sites and web applications. It is an amplification of the power of open source (lowering the barrier to being able to look at and modify the source).
- **Javascript is weakly typed**: True, but if you are going to do math operations on large datasets then you are going to use Typed Arrays which are fixed size and have elements with fixed types/sizes. In addition, type inference (in Firefox 9) significantly increases performance related to variable reference.
- **Javascript is prototype based**: prototype based inheritance is more expressive than standard class based inheritance and with a few sugar functions you can do pretty standard class based inheritance in Javascript: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html
- **WebSockets**: I don't think you asked a question regarding WebSockets. And yes, they are a great addition to the platform, particularly the newest iteration of the protocol and API which allows Typed Arrays and Blob data to be sent and received directly.

**Opinion**:

WebGL and Javascript performance are not yet to the level where you could port the latest AAA first person shooters. However, I might suggest that the real money to be made in the near future with 3D games is with casual web games. This has already proven true with casual 2D games on the web and WebGL is getting pervasive enough that it is ripe for successful casual 3D games.

Also, if you have a large investment in C/C++ 3D libraries, then you might consider [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) which is a compiler that target Javascript and has surprisingly good performance.

Comment: Another good answer, while I generally agree that the source should be available to everyone, some things are simply proprietary and of great value. Copyright is all good and well, but leaving sophisticated, proprietary solutions out cold is not good for us. While we intend to release old engines as open source when their time goes, currently with all the optimizations in place, clever occlusion culling, even a realtime radiosity renderer which simplifies geometry in a prepass and employs rational raytracing afterwards to resolve subtle global illumination effects as color bleeding...

Comment: A deferred renderer (not really dancing with WebGL because of the status of MRTs, so we are exploring the old forward rendering approach with various optimizations), even realtime on-GPU experiments with SHL (lower iterations). There's a lot to protect. And while I agree with your point on large datasets, with all the clever approaches, it will prove to be a bottleneck in the future. People will enjoy these technologies and will definitely demand more in the future. And -more- will be CPU-bound.

Comment: While on desktop or embedded platforms you have cryptic disassembly to battle, be my guest to reverse engineer all the algorithms. If you can reverse engineer our code, you are a bright lad who could develop such a technology much faster than decrypting pieces of it. Here, it's all open here. It seems that for now it'll be best to re-engineer a classic approach which doesn't need to be hidden because it's general knowledge. But that's a shame because we've got some really nice stuff running at the office.

Comment: P.S. Thank you for Emscripten, but I have a personal rule that dictates usage of open source software only when developing for the open source community. Taking and giving. Taking squared is not what I want to do. But this has given me some ideas about approaching it from a new angle. Anyways, much obliged! Only thing completely free for me is knowledge. And in that respect, I have a few papers on the way which will illuminate on the ideas of our engine, but not actually distribute it freely, which is understandable.

Comment: If it's important for you then given your background, it should be pretty easy for you to develop a robust, sophisticated and efficient Javascript obfuscator. Consider for a moment [jslinux](http://bellard.org/jslinux/). This is an x86 emulator executing compiled code (Linux kernel) in Javascript. Obviously, you don't want to emulate your real code, but the point is that you can obfuscate your Javascript code to any level that is useful. But it will be some level of tradeoff between obfuscation and load speed.

Comment: True, everything is about tradeoffs. We do have some working techniques, but they require refinement. I guess that's the way to go. Thank you for all of your input! Weekend's coming, there'll be time to investigate such approaches. The only thing that matters that it doesn't hamper performance. It's strained enough as it is.

Comment: @DomagojPandža. That's a strange personal rule since in modern software development you can't possibly avoid using open source tools to build your software. And open source developers are not expecting or demanding that people that use their software tools also release the results. Any software project of sufficient size uses dozens or hundreds of open source libraries. Just consider that most uses of zlib/deflate are based on open source code. Or look at the license file for iOS which references hundreds of open source libraries. Even the Windows network stack originated in BSD.

Comment: It's more of a justification for me to explore these options on my own. I have a real hunger. I need to understand everything I'm doing. To do it on my own. Only when I completely understand it, can I turn to some solutions. It's a blessing and a curse. There's nothing sweeter than basking the glory of your own solutions, but there is nothing more bitter than running into a wall. It's a little contradictory, but it has made me push myself and understand what I'm doing. "By using the technology of the mass relays, your society develops along the paths we desire." - Sovereign, Mass Effect

Comment: @kanaka - An X86 emulator in JavaScript. I'm impressed.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is very interesting, especially the obfuscation part. Me myself was in the console/desktop games industry for many, many years before I switched to the web like 6-7 years ago. At first, the view-source was very strange to me. But slowly I've come to love it and think differently about technology solutions.

True, it costs a lot of money to develop high-end tech and also true, it's very easy to copy your ideas and solutions. It's also true that you won't be able to copyright them or protect them in any way the moment you publish them. But is that really a problem? I think this inspiring talk...

http://www.ted.com/talks/lang/en/johanna_blakley_lessons_from_fashion_s_free_culture.html

...about how it works in fashion industry really nails it - to stay successful you need to be on your toes and keep developing. Whatever you put out is done and history, now what's next?

The advantage you still have is your tools and pipeline, which from my experience is more expensive and complicated than the actual rendering part. And that you already have an experienced team and game up and running, which you hopefully successfully monetize upon.

Also, a side note really, I feel the online-experience is more about the social aspects rather than the graphical, which in many ways reside server-side and thus protected.

Looking forward to your game!